# JQuery File Upload to NGINX/PHP server fails when over 1.5GB

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, nginx, jquery-file-upload

I'm uploading large files using JQuery File Upload to an NGINX server with the PHP backend. The upload works for files up to and around 2GB but larger files around 6 or 8GB reach the end but show the following error message

```
The uploaded file was only partially uploaded
```

[image]

I've updated my nginx.conf:

```
http {
        sendfile           on;
        keepalive_timeout  65;

        server {
 ...
                client_max_body_size 20000000M;

 ...
        }
}
```

And my php.ini for php-fpm:

```
memory_limit = 512000000M

upload_max_filesize = 0 

post_max_size = 200000M

max_execution_time = 4320000

max_input_time = 4320000
```

The file upload take under an hour to complete in all cases.

Here is Chrome's Inspect Element output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hן Ben I suspect your php.ini settings - can you describe which server are you using CMS maybe? try adding a ini get to all the critical settings to be sure they are followed by your server just before the upload starts.

Comment: Also try using `ini_set()` before the file upload and uncrease limitations for `session.gc_maxlifetime`, `session.cookie_lifetime`, `session.cache_expire`. Last thing try setting a limitation to `upload_max_filesize` that is not unlimited.

Comment: I'm using NGINX server with php-fpm. @ShlomiHassid

Comment: I've added in   ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 9999999999999999);
  ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 9999999999999999);
  ini_set('session.cache_expire', 9999999999999999);
 and set upload_max_filesize to 500000000M but see the same error.

Comment: Really curious, how do you accurately test a 2.0 GB file upload in development without waiting hours??

Comment: It takes about 35minutes to fail to upload a 4GB file on my connection.

Comment: What's platform of your server? 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: And what's in the error_log?

Comment: The error log shows lots of the following: 2014/03/24 16:16:00 [notice] 20743#0: *19800 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /usr/local/nginx/client_body_temp/0044852691, client: 82.45.135.2, server: chew.tv, request: "POST /actions/upload HTTP/1.1", host: "chew.tv", referrer: "https://chew.tv/account/upload"

Comment: @VBart and the platform is x86_64

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with php.ini or jquery uploader.

Just monitor your system resources closely to get close to the solution:

1. uploaded files are saved in temp folders (monitor this closely).
2. Your system RAM resource.
3. Your system storage capacity.

Beside these possibilities, check if your host/environment truncate long POST requests (by time or amount of data travelled)

Comment: Thanks prady the server resources are fine. I might try changing the tmp folder but it's strange that it works for files as large as 1.6GB

Comment: Do timeout and keepalive_timeout setting effect large uploads?

Comment: Yes, they do try making them -1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

There was  issue in PHP 5.3 while uploading file with size more than 2gb. It was solved in PHP 5.4 if i am not mistaken.

Comment: I'm running PHP 5.4.25 on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to upload a file using a plain form?
eg:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Also I would try to setup a nginx server locally to cut down upload time. If it still fails you can rule out timeouts and even filesystem/disk issues.